# Most recent tectonic plate data

Tags: data, vector, geology

What is the latest update to the positions of the tectonic plates? Does anyone have a most up-to-date shapefile or vector of the tectonic plates?

Answer (score 3):

I think USGS data is the latest one. That can be reached at [here](http://earthquake.usgs.gov/learn/kml.php). ESRI also has data of it at [here](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=f155b76c13c84f62864446847f1ae652).For movement information of plates you may a have a look at the NASA site at [here](http://sideshow.jpl.nasa.gov/post/series.html).A [research](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1029/2001GC000252/full) data (2002) can be reached at [here](http://peterbird.name/oldFTP/) and further research is at [here](https://github.com/fraxen/tectonicplates).

Comment: Unfortunately no metadata mentionning the date in this source...

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a reliable source too: https://github.com/fraxen/tectonicplates/blob/master/README.md